# How can I migrate a repo from gitlab to gihub which already has the old version of the repo?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

For some reasons, we used to migrate our project from github to gitlab about half a year ago. However, we find a lot of backwards of gitlab during the half year and now wanna move back to github.

The problem is **an old version of the same project still kept on github**, and most of the tutorials I found are based on creating a new repo on github. **Is there any way to utilize the migration and need not to create a new repo?**

Comment: git push --mirror? Never used it, but seems to do what you want. Or maybe you just want to keep the current heads, and use git push --all.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a git repo already, you can just change the origin to github and push directly there.

```
git remote rename origin gitlab # Keep the old reference to gitlab
git remote add origin GITHUB_REPO_URL
git push --tags origin master # (and other branches too)
```

Then, you can just work right off of github again.